# Duplicate record from one Column and distinct for another Column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to write a select statement to retrieve duplicate records of a given customer who has multiple phone number. I want only the unique phone to be displayed. Ex: Data in the table

```
Customer Number Phone Number
123             408-211-1234
123             408-211-1234
123             321-456-7890
123             321-123-4567
345             897-345-1010
```

Output

```
Customer Number Phone Number
123             408-211-1234
123             321-456-7890
123             321-123-4567
345             897-345-1010
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by including "DISTINCT" in the SELECT statement, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_number, phone_number FROM my_table;
```

Using `SELECT DISTINCT` is the generally encouraged way to have a distinct set returned (note that the DISTINCT applies to the entire row being returned; if there are multiple phone numbers for a given customer_number, they will all be returned).

Another approach, however, is to use a GROUP BY, like so:

```
SELECT customer_number, phone_number
FROM my_tabl
GROUP BY customer_number, phone_number;
```

Using a `GROUP BY` allows you to also use aggregates, should you choose, like so:

```
SELECT customer_number, phone_number, count(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY customer_number, phone_number;
```

The above will return the number of times a given "customer_number and phone_number" are repeated in the table.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. What if i need all the columns in a given table?

Comment: I tried this: select * from table_name where (phone_number) IN (select distinct phone_number from table_name order by phone_number);

Comment: If the other columns have identical contents across rows, then you can simply add them to the SELECT DISTINCT column list, or to the SELECT and GROUP BY lists for the GROUP BY query.  You can also do: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_name;

Comment: It's actually a customer table with different data. Some are identical, some unique. I'm interested only to retrieve customer with multiple customer_number and have unique multiple phone_numbers, and rest of the data that are part of this row.

Comment: In the cases where there are multiple values in the other columns for the rows which you wish to extract, you need to tell the database which value you want.  This can be accomplished with the GROUP BY syntax by using an aggregate function for the other columns.  For instance, if you wish to have the minimum value from the set for the "value" column the query would be:  SELECT customer_number, phone_number, min(value) FROM table GROUP BY customer_number, phone_number.